# Problema para acceder a setState o state desde function

Tags: reactjs

Estoy intentando cambiar el state de una propiedad cuando hago click en el boton, pero rompe la app.

En el state declaro las propiedades que necesito manejar, y todas funcionan correctamente.

```
 this.state = {
            cantidad: 1,
            MontoCargado: this.props.Dolares,
            Dolares: 0,
            IdLink: this.props.IdLink,
            IdCredito: this.props.IdCredito,
        };
```

En la funcion declarada, cuando hago click me sale error como si la propiedad `cantidad` no existiera.

```
    CrearBotonEvento() {
        console.log(this.state.cantidad);
        console.log('Entre');
    }

 <button onClick={this.CrearBotonEvento}>Crear Boton </button>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo acceder al state desde un evento onChange creado para un input, pero no desde el evento del click del boton.

Comment: *En la funcion declarada, cuando hago click me sale error como si la propiedad cantidad no existiera.* -> Esto no es cierto, lo que te está diciendo que no existe es `this`, no `cantidad`. El error dice *No se puede leer la propiedad `state` de undefined*. Prueba a hacer un `console.log(this);` a ver qué pasa :)

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, estoy incursionando en react, al hacer console.log(this) me dice: undefined

Comment: Nunca he usado react, pero por lo que veo, necesitas bindear el método `CrearBotonEvento` igual que has bindeado el `EventoIngresarColones` para poder acceder a `this` en él.

Comment: @Benito-B gracias, era la solucion y no lo habia notado. Fijate si lo pones como respuesta asi la acepto

Comment: No voy a poner una respuesta de algo de lo que no tengo absolutamente ni idea :). Lo único que hice fue, literalmente, mirar la [documentación de React](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)... En serio, SO apenas tendría usuarios si la gente se acostumbrase a consultar la *documentación oficial* de lo que están usando. Si quieres, escribe tú una respuesta explicando la solución y luego podrás aceptarla

Comment: estuve leyendo la doc de react y en ningun momento en el ejemplo que dan dice que bind debe hacerse si o si. https://es.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Cómo que no??? Cito literalmente la documentación: *Tienes que tener mucho cuidado en cuanto al significado de this en los callbacks de JSX. **En JavaScript, los métodos de clase no están ligados por defecto. Si olvidas ligar this.handleClick y lo pasas a onClick, this será undefined cuando se llame la función**.*

Comment: Claro tienes razon, debo haber leido rapido o no comprendido ese parrafo. gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema parece ser que pierde el contexto del documento y al hacerle bind este se lo pasa. En el constructor queda declarado de esta forma.

```
 this.CrearBotonEvento = this.CrearBotonEvento.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tambien puedes definir tu metodo como **arrrow function** =>.

ejemplo:

```
CrearBotonEvento=()=> {
        console.log(this.state.cantidad);
        console.log('Entre');
}
<button onClick={this.CrearBotonEvento}>Crear Boton </button>
```

otra opción

```
CrearBotonEvento(){
            console.log(this.state.cantidad);
            console.log('Entre');
    }
    <button onClick={() => this.CrearBotonEvento()}>Crear Boton </button>
```

ó

```
<button onClick={this.CrearBotonEvento.bind(this)}>Crear Boton </button>;
```

Comment: Aunque funciona, en la documentación se menciona que el primer ejemplo es experimental, y se recomienda su uso junto con un [plug-in Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties), si no se esta usando create-react-app

Comment: las `arrow function` no manejan this, cuidado al usarlas